# Unable to delete dashboard and visualizations through Kibana GUI

Tags: curl, kibana-4

I am unable to delete dashboard and visualizations through Kibana GUI. There are no error messages as well that are displayed.

Is this a bug? I am using Kibana 4.4.
Is there a curl command that I can use as a workaround?

Comment: have you got any solution ?